# jQuery: keeping references to jQuery object during application runtime

Tags: jquery

I've got a question about treating references to jQuery objects.

Let suppose in my app I have a DOM element DIV with ID=some_widget, it is supposed to live during all the application runtime and be used quite often in the code.

1) So if I keep a reference to it in a global var during application runtime:

```
var someWidget = $("#some_widget")
```

it will create jquery objects once, but will consume memory during application run, but when I use someWidget it wont create jquery object again, so this can speed up the process.

2) if I will alway use the call of $("#some_widget") in the code, it won't consume memory constantly, but every time I use $. it will take time jQuery to construct the object.

Am I right? What approach is more sufficient?
Can keeping the references to many object end up with memory leak?
what does it depend on, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cache your jQuery object by declaring it in a variable. This is in fact considered a best practice for re-used objects.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding (although still a jQuery novice myself) is that the saving by caching the jQuery object comes from the fact that the DOM is not traversed each time you call the selector. So, for example, if you call `$("#some_widget")` multiple times in your code, jQuery will traverse the DOM each time to find the element with that ID. If you cache it once in the variable, then you can call jQuery methods on it the same as you would with the selector, but the DOM traversal is not required. I have done this in my code with realized performance improvements. I am not aware of any issues with memory leaks using the caching method, and much of my reading on the topic recommends caching as a best practice.

One other aside that can be helpful if you do this is adding a naming convention to cache variables of this type. For example, prepending a $ to the variable:

```
var $someWidget = $("#some_widget");
```

Some people don't like this, but I have found it useful when visually tracking which variables I can use jQuery functions on.

Comment: I'm one of those people; the extra $ makes it quite clear to me that I'm dealing with a cached jQuery object. I use it to make $this variables all the time (from $(this)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Only thing I would like to add is
`var query_result = $("some_selector")` is actually caching your query results into a variable for a later use. If the result of the query happens to be a widget, then that is being cached. Obvious advantage will be that when you are using this cached query, jQuery won't have to query the DOM again to build up results for you. But the disadvantage will be that the cached results are like a snapshot of the DOM at the instant when query was executed. So if at a later stage the dom has been manipulated, executing the `$("previous_selector")` will return something different than cached `query_result` and it might not be what you are expecting.

Not entirely sure about memory leaks, have seen lot of programmers use this caching technique and is recommended too.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But what do you mean "if at a later stage the dom has been manipulated, executing the $("previous_selector") will return something different", what different it can return if its a widget? example?

Comment: You are just considering it from a widget point of view. 
For example lets say your DOM is like this at page load: 
`<ul class="foo"><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>`. Now you cached all list items `var li_list = $(".foo li")`. Right now you you have 2 "li" cached in `li_list`. 

Later you manipulated you DOM and it became something like this: 
`<ul class="foo"><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>`, if you were to run query again 'var new_list  = $(".foo li")' the variable `new_list` will have 3 li items, where as original `li_list` has just two. 

I hope this explains it.

Comment: Yes if "widget" is an array of jq objects, it wont be dynamically updated. But if you get only on DOM element as widget (as in my example DIV) you will probably won't find such manipulation for this object that could lead to some problems in terms of what you described, no?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In that case you don't have to worry about this sort of a problem.